# rewrite language extension in URLs with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some troubles with url rewrites in htaccess.

I have all my PHP pages in subfolder /pages.

**These are my urls:**
http://www.example/tickets 
http://www.example/en/tickets
http://www.example/fr/tickets
http://www.example/nl/tickets

--> all these should point to /pages/tickets.php

Currently I use this in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(nl|fr|en)/tickets /pages/tickets.php [L]
```

The urls WITH language string work but when I ommit the language string I get a 404 error.

How can I solve this?

Comment: doesn't seem to do the trinck. I'm still getting a 404 page :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this rule to remove the language identifier for all following rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(nl|fr|en)/(.*) $1
```

Or, if you just want it to be optional for this single rule:

```
RewriteRule ^((nl|fr|en)/)?tickets$ /pages/tickets.php [L]
```

Answer (score -1):

This also works:

```
Redirect 301 /nl/ / Redirect 301 /fr/ / Redirect 301 /en/ /
```